# Why am I getting (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: java

Here are some code examples I used but cannot understand why this is happening.

> Not Working code (1)

```
Files.copy(Paths.get(path), Paths.get(".").resolve("test.svg"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
canvas.setURI("test.svg");
```

> Working code (2)

```
Files.copy(Paths.get(path), Paths.get(".").resolve("test.svg"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
canvas.setURI("../../test.svg");
```

> Not Working code (3)

```
Files.copy(Paths.get(path), Paths.get("images").resolve("test.svg"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
canvas.setURI("../../images/test.svg");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just in case someone else has the same issue,

it has nothing to do with the size of the file.
The problem is that in some svg files there are some `clip-path` attributes.

When the image is inside a folder, then batik cannot resolve this path, means that assuming that the `image.svg` is inside folder `images` the following code will not work:

```
jsvgcanvas.setURI("images/image.svg");
```

but if the same image is not inside a folder, but inside the home folder that the project is, it will work:

```
jsvgcanvas.setURI("image.svg");
```

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as what I said before `FileNotFoundException` is because the file is now where you are looking.

Your *working* code vs *not working* code is in **no way** equivalent and still are not doing any debugging to see what the actual paths that are **incorrectly** specifying actually are.

Instead of embedding chained method calls into methods, assign the results to a reference variable and step debug to it to see what its value actually is, it is not what you think it is for sure.

At least `System.out.println()` their `Path.toAbsolutePath()` and you will see why they are incorrect and why I should have left this closed to begin with.

#### Relative Directories

`.` means current working directory whatever it may be

`../..` means up two directories from `.`

`images` means `./images` and `../../images` means go `up two directories from` .`and then use`./images`

`Paths.get(".").resolve("test.svg")` will be `./test.svg`

and

`Paths.get("images").resolve("test.svg")` will be `./images/test.svg`

`./test.svg` is obviously **not** the same thing as `./images/test.svg`

That is why you should always work with [`Path.toAbsolutePath()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toAbsolutePath()) so you know exactly where they are pointing to.

You just are not building the path correctly, what *correctly* is only you can tell.